# Is there a (tidy) way to calculate a rolling window excluding center values?

Tags: r, dplyr, window, rolling-computation

i am trying to wrap my head around how to calculate a rolling standard deviation for a window spanning [-10,10], excluding the three days at the center [-1,1]. Do you know a tidy solution?

I experimented with the slide_period_vec() - this is quite convenient as it respects the date format and spacing and my panel is not balanced (and I want to avoid bloating it with 80% NA's to make it balanced)

Is there any way to adjust '.before' and '.after' to obtain [-10,-2] and [2,10] in one pass?

```
set.seed(4711)
daily_data <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "day"),
                          value = rnorm(730, mean = 50, sd = 10))


daily_data <- daily_data %>% 
  mutate(SD = slide_period_vec(daily_data$value,
                                   .i = daily_data$date,
                                   .period = "day",
                                   .f = sd,
                                   .before =10,
                                   .after = 10,
                                   .complete = F)
```

Have nice day!

Comment: What package is `slide_period_vec` from?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any function that will automatically group all lagged and leading values based on a custom index (e.g., [-10, -2] and then [2, 10] so here is a custom function that creates new columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

add_lag_lead <- function(df, lag_n, lead_n) {
  bind_cols(
    map_dfc(
      lag_n, 
      function(lag_i) {
        df %>% 
          mutate(!!sym(str_c("value_lag_", lag_i)) := lag(value, lag_i)) %>%
          select(last_col())
      }
    ),
    map_dfc(
      lead_n, 
      function(lead_i) {
        df %>% 
          mutate(!!sym(str_c("value_lead_", lead_i)) := lead(value, lead_i)) %>%
          select(last_col())
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Then with that custom function you can write a row-wise operation using `rowwise` and select your custom index of lagged and leading values:

```r
daily_data_withSD <- bind_cols(
  daily_data, 
  add_lag_lead(daily_data, lag_n = 2:10, lead_n = 2:10) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    summarize(sd_rolling = sd(c_across(value_lag_2:value_lead_10), na.rm = TRUE)) # replace with mutate() if you want to see all columns
)

daily_data_withSD

# A tibble: 730 × 3
   date       value sd_rolling
   <date>     <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01  53.2       6.63
 2 2022-01-02  65.3       6.70
 3 2022-01-03  45.7       6.74
 4 2022-01-04  43.9       7.62
 5 2022-01-05  56.9       7.16
 6 2022-01-06  43.3       7.93
 7 2022-01-07  43.7       7.62
 8 2022-01-08  57.6       7.80
 9 2022-01-09  53.6       8.66
10 2022-01-10  38.9       8.50
# … with 720 more rows
```